# Possible to cast generic list of type to a generic list of its super type?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, generics

trying to do below, but don't know enough about reflection obviously.

Example of what I'm trying to do is, I want to "resolve" a list of JazzDancer into a list of Dancer (which all dancer types inherit from). Want to make sure that if DanceStyle here is Jazz, only JazzDancer type will be in the list of dancers. hope this make sense.

Problem is that it seems that you can't cast List to List.

Is that even possible?

```
List<Dancer> dancers = TypeNameResolver<Dancer>.ResolveList(DanceStyle, typeof(Dancer));


public static List<T> ResolveList(IDanceStyle style, Type toType)
        {
            Type list = typeof (List<>);
            Type[] pars = { TypeNameResolver<T>.Resolve(style,toType).GetType()};
            List<T> result = (List<T>)Activator.CreateInstance(list.MakeGenericType(pars));
            return result;
        }

public static T Resolve(IDanceStyle style, Type toType)
{
    Assembly a = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    var typeName = style.GetType().Name + toType.Name;
    var toTypeNameSpace = toType.Namespace;
    return (T)a.CreateInstance(toTypeNameSpace + "." + typeName);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need reflection for this. LINQ, on the other hand, can help here:

```
List<JazzDancer> myListOfJazzDancers = ...;
List<Dancer> myListOfDancers = myListOfJazzDancers.Cast<Dancer>().ToList()
```

Comment: thank you, it works. then i realized that i can't really cast list of JazzDancers into list of Dancers and still have them be as JazzDancers, when it's possible to do that via using list<dancers> .Add method and adding in actual instances of JazzDancers there.

Comment: @andryuha: Well, you can cast them to JazzDancers after retrieving them, if you are sure that the list only contains JazzDancers. On the other hand, if you are sure that it only contains JazzDancers, you might as well use a `List<JazzDancers>` in the first place...

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a Linq query:

```
dancers = jazzDancers.Cast<Dancer>();
```

If you need to do some kind of check on each jazzDancer, you just add a `Where` such as:

```
dancers = jazzDancers.Where(jd => jd.SomeFiels == Something).Cast<Dancer>();
```